# How to get index being tested on where block using spock?

Tags: grails, groovy, spock

Is there any way to get the index being tested on Spock?
I have a where block like this:

```
where:
column1 | column2
1 | 3
1 | 4
2 | 5
6 | 8
```

I want to know if it's possible to get the index being executed on my test.
So If I'm running the first test (1 | 3) my index would be 0.
If I'm running the third test (2 | 5) my index would be 2.

Is there any way to get this index inside my test?

Answer (score 1):

The trivial answer would be to add an index or case or some categorical variable that can be checked in the result section.

```
where:
    idx | column1 | column2
    0   | 1       | 3
    1   | 1       | 4
    2   | 2       | 5
    3   | 6       | 8
```

But I have to wonder if the where clause is being used to run what maybe should be multiple test cases under the guise of a single test.

The idx shouldn't be telling the test code what checks to execute in the expect/then block, and shouldn't be driving any code that is being tested.

If the test yields different results if the order of the inputs was:

```
where:
    idx | column1 | column2
    0   | 6       | 8
    1   | 2       | 5
    2   | 1       | 4
    3   | 1       | 3
```

then I think the test needs to be broken up, because order sensitivity would seem to indicate that this test is testing something other than just the pairs of column1 and column2 values, and using where isn't exactly appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

There is a default (now?): `#iterationCount`, see [here](https://dzone.com/articles/unrolling-spock-advanced). You can use it in your method's name like

```
@Unroll
def "testing entry #iterationCount from where block"() { 
  // ...
}
```

There is `#featureName` available as well, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add, `@Unroll` to your test definition and then in the test name put `#column1` to output the value

```
@Unroll
def "something #column1 and #column2"() { 
  ...
 }
```

Comment: It's not that... I need the index inside the test itself... to do something like "if(indexBeingTested == 0) do that, else if(indexBeingTested > 3), do that"

Comment: Here's the docs https://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/data_driven_testing.html

Comment: You probably need to add another parameter to your test, but if you're running certain code based on an index that seems odd. That logic should be in your service.

Answer (score 0):

Something like below would suffice?

```
import spock.lang.*

@Unroll
class MyFirstSpec extends Specification {

  def "column1 is #column1 and column2 is #column2 where index is #index"() {
    expect:
    if(index in [0, 1]) {
        assert column1 < column2
    } else {
        assert column1 == column2
    }

    where:
    [column1, column2, index] << [
        [1, 2, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5]
    ].transpose().withIndex()*.flatten()    
  }
}
```

Run this [<kbd>**Sample**</kbd>](https://meetspock.appspot.com/script/5074387359236096)

*Note:*
[`withIndex()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#withIndex(java.lang.Iterable)) is available from Groovy 2.4.0

Comment: Seems like you have been writing so much of logic just to test things which is very bad thing. We must write minimum code in our test case to pass the code and vice-versa.

Comment: Exactly. The question is not to figure out whether it is good/bad to write so much logic in test. The answer is just a viable solution to a problem. The code in the test makes OP ask the question to himself as you did :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding an index column can be done in a groovy way. Just add the following line to the end of the "where:" block. The list should have the same number of items as the rows of data

```
idx << [0,1,2,3]
```

or

```
idx << (0..3).collect()
```

Reference: Secton "Combining Data Tables, Data Pipes, and Variable Assignments" of http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/data_driven_testing.html